# Laravel Get ancestors (URL)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In Laravel, I have a table which contains id, parent_id, slug (Self-referring),

When I have an ID, I need to get all its ancestors in a format like this (Separated by "/").

```
level1/level2/level3
```

But in an efficient way without a package like "laravel-nestedset
".

I have implemented it like this.

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Collection', 'parent_id');
}

public function getParentsAttribute()
{
    $parents = collect([]);

    $parent = $this->parent;

    while(!is_null($parent)) {
        $parents->push($parent);
        $parent = $parent->parent;
    }

    return $parents;
}
```

Any other way to do it efficiently and separated by "/" ?

Comment: I think this is already a good solution. Also that the `parents` attribute returns a collection (might be a plain array though). Then just call `$collection->implode('/')` to make it into a string

Comment: do you have a column named level in the DB with the level?  if you did you could dynamically build a query to get all parents then use something like `GROUP_CONCAT`  and let the DB do the leg work - PS I don't use Laravel, but I have done this with nested sets, simple parent child relationships are a bit harder because you need a join for each level.

Comment: Any way to do it using eloquent "with()" - Eager loading?

Comment: @Flame You mean like `return Collection::find(33)->parents->implode('/');` ?

Comment: yes i think that works since `->parents->` will refer to your attribute getter. You might be able to add `protected $appends = ['parents']` to your model to automatically have this property filled

Comment: @Flame I also thought the same, But it gets me a blank white screen. :(

Comment: @stackminu try debugging the parents collection itself to check if its empty or put breakpoints in your getter

Comment: @Flame Parent collection returns all fields with the "parent".

Comment: oh sorry ofcourse `parent` is an object, you should be calling it like `->implode('yourproperty', '/')` in where `yourproperty` is a property of the parent object. The single-parameter call only works if your collection only has simple scalar values

Comment: @Flame Awesome it worked But getting the result reversed. :/

Comment: in this link, you could see two different approaches for dealing with hierarchical data in a relational database http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little conversation in the comments I think this is a good solution:

```
// YourModel.php

// Add this line of you want the "parents" property to be populated all the time.
protected $appends = ['parents'];

public function getParentsAttribute()
{
    $collection = collect([]);
    $parent = $this->parent;
    while($parent) {
        $collection->push($parent);
        $parent = $parent->parent;
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

Then you can retrieve your parents using:

- `YourModel::find(123)->parents` (collection instance)
- `YourModel::find(123)->parents->implode('yourprop', '/')` (imploded to string, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-implode)
- `YourModel::find(123)->parents->reverse()->implode('yourprop', '/')` (reversed order https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-reverse)

As noted by Nikolai Kiselev https://stackoverflow.com/a/55103589/1346367 you may also combine it with this to save a few queries:

```
protected $with = ['parent.parent.parent'];
// or inline:
YourModel::find(123)->with(['parent.parent.parent']);
```

This preloads the parent on object load. If you decide not to use this, the parent is (lazy) loaded as soon as you call `$yourModel->parent`.

Comment: Sorry, just have one more question related to this. Any way to get the annsestor and the self ? `level1/level2/level3/WITH-THIS`.

Comment: I guess you could just push `$this` to the $collection inside `getParentsAttribute()`, you might want to put the `reverse()` method in there as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many levels maximum could be nested you can use Eager Loading. Let's say if maximum depth is 3 levels you can do:

```
$model->with('parent.parent.parent');
```

You can also use recursion instead of loop.

```
public function getParentsAttribute()
{
    if (!$this->parent) {
        return collect([]);
    }

    return collect($this->parent->parents)->push($this->parent);
}
```

In case you want to add the first one object too (self) the full call will be:

```
$model->parents->push($model)->reverse->implode('attr_name', '/');
```

Which you can also wrap into attribute

```
public function getPathAttribute() {
    return $model->parents->push($model)->reverse->implode('attr_name', '/');
}
```

And call like `$model->path;`

Comment: This makes it quite unhandy though since you will get your parents nested as well in your object. You will have to access them using `$mainObject->parent->parent->parent` so it is not handy if you want an array of parents

Comment: @Flame, true but at least less queries

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev why do you think this solution execute less query? for retrieve full trees in Adjacency List Model we need to join based on our tree's depth. (in this example 3)

Comment: I am not sure if this actually resolves to 1 query, even if it does, the speed increase is arguable since you are trading of a PHP loop to create an array of parents from this nested property, VS the original solution that does 3 small queries and pushes them in a PHP array

Comment: @hoseinz3, each time `$parent->parent` is called in the `while` loop of `getParentsAttribute()` will trigger a new DB query unless those nested relationships were preloaded before

Comment: @Flame seems your solution is good, but it can be combined with Eager loading, no harm :)

Comment: @stackminu you could use a recursion, I've updated the answer.