# How to get parent categories for current category in Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

There is a table named Categories (id, parent_id, name).

The purpose is to print something like this directly from controller:

**Current path is:**
**Electronics>Computers>Peripherals>Videocards (we are here)**

Videocards `parent_id` points to Peripherals, which points to Computers and so on, up to main category with `parent_id=0`, where iteration stops.

I'm getting current path this way:

```
public function listCategories(Request $request)
    {
        $catID = $request->id;
        $currentCat = \App\Categories::find($catID);
      
        // Current path to be shown here
        echo '<h5>Current path: '.$currentCat->name.'</h5>';
    }
```

I believe that I need some iteration here, so I can later print all parent categories using foreach.

**UPDATE: Solution is here:** [Laravel Get ancestors (URL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103315/laravel-get-ancestors-url/55103589#55103589)

Comment: If you have a lot of potential levels of nesting, you may want to consider a "nested set" approach. Something like https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset or https://github.com/etrepat/baum

Comment: Welcome to SO. If your question turns out to be a duplicate, please close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a recursive function that does the job !

First declare a hasParent function in your category model to decide weather the instance has a parent or not

**Category.php**

```
public function getHasParentAttribute(){
 
   return $this->parent_id !=0 ;
}
```

Then declare a function that will get you the ancestor and format the path for you

```
function  ParentNode($path,child){
If(child->hasParent){
        $path = child->Parent->name .">" . $path; 
        ParentNode($path,child->Parent);    
         }
        return $path;
     }
```

Then, in your controller you just need to call the function and provide to it an initial path and the child category you want to retrieve it's ancestors

**Controller.php**

```
$child = Category::findOrFail($id);
$path = $child->name;
ParentNode($path,$child);
```

It will access every ancestor till it finds that there is no other parent and return the final path

PS : there must be a function in the Category model that returns the Parent instance of the model